# php syntax check ','

Tags: php

Tengo un problema para concatenar una consulta con order by

```
...ORDER BY post_author DESC, post_date DESC;
```

Esta consulta funciona en mysql perfectamente. Pero en php no se cómo agregar la coma (,)

'orderA' es post_author
'orderB' es DESC 
'orderC' es post_Date

```
 return $s['orderA']." ".$s['orderB']."  ".$s['orderC']." ".$s['orderB'];
```

cómo agrego la coma entre ".$s['orderB']." y ".$s['orderC']."

gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si te entendí bien creo que la respuesta seria:

```
return $s['orderA']." ".$s['orderB'].", ".$s['orderC']." ".$s['orderB'].";";
```

Comment: ok. ya había probado esa forma y no funcionaba por eso pregunté, la volví a probar y funciona, creo que era otro error el que interfería